# Creating a defaultProps with createTheme in MUI v5 not working

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using Material-UI v5 for the first time, and I want to create a custom theme with `createTheme` to style a button component. According to the [documentation](https://mui.com/customization/theme-components/#global-style-overrides):

> The theme's `components` key allows you to customize a component without wrapping it in another component. You can change the styles, the default props, and more.

They provide a code example:

```
const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    // Name of the component
    MuiButtonBase: {
      defaultProps: {
        // The props to change the default for.
        disableRipple: true, // No more ripple!
      },
    },
  },
});
```

But when I try to implement it there doesn't seem to be a components key with the `createTheme`. I get the following error:

```
Argument of type '{ components: any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ThemeOptions'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'components' does not exist in type 'ThemeOptions'
```

What might be the problem here?

Comment: Are you using MUI v4 or v5?

Comment: If you are using typescript, you may need to define the property types of your themes: https://mui.com/customization/theming/

Comment: I'm using v5 @NearHuscarl

Comment: Your code works fine on v5, can you prepare a codesandbox?

Comment: I am using typescript, but I thought that was only needed when creating custom variables @BrunoFarias

Comment: @NearHuscarl My first question here, so not sure how this works, but here is codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/cold-sea-mlqgx?file=/src/App.tsx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using MUI v5, but you import `createTheme` from v4, which doesn't have the `components` property in `createTheme`, so change the import path to:

```
import { createTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";
```

From:

```
import { createTheme } from "@material-ui/core";
```